# Calculating power of (1-1/x)^y for very large x,y

Tags: python, numpy, floating-accuracy

I am thinking about calculating $(1-1/x)^y$ for very large x,y numbers in python.
One way todo so, it to use `exp(y*log1p(-1/x))`, but I am not sure about its accuracy.

Are they any results on using such accuracy? e.g., bound the error of such result?

I guess it better than using the approximation `exp(-y/x))`.

Comment: I used [Herbie](https://herbie.uwplse.org/demo/) and it suggested the same `exp(y*log1p(-1/x))` formula. What's your value range?

Comment: The `exp(y*log1p(-1/x))` formula looks well behaved—each operation has the usual rounding error, but they do not involve complications like subtracting values of similar magnitude. Accuracy would largely depend on the accuracy of the `exp` and `log1p` implementations—math library routines are not always implemented with ideal accuracy. Aside from that, I expect you could write error bounds caused by the usual floating-point rounding and they would be modest.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely there  will be accuracy concerns, especially for very large x and y. You can use *result = math.expm1(y * math.log1p(-1/x))* this will calculate higher precision for values close to zero.
Alternately,egarding error bounds, it's challenging to provide a general bound without knowing specific ranges for x and y.
However, you can consider using numerical libraries that provide functions specifically designed for high precision, such as the mpmath library in Python. mpmath allows you to perform arithmetic with arbitrary precision:

```
from mpmath import mp

mp.dps = 50  # Set the desired precision (adjust as needed)
x=100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
y=100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    
result = mp.exp(y * mp.log1p(-1/mp.mpf(x)))

print(result)

#output
Result:0.36787944117144232159552377016146086744581113103177
```

Comment: I think it is an error to use expm1 instead of exp. But thnaks for the mpmath :)